# How to avoid word-wrapping when changing the font-size of a single word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

**Synopsis:** I have a paragraph of text and when I move the mouse over any single word, I would like its font size to increase, then decrease again upon mouse leave.

**Problem:** This works fine for some paragraphs, however for others upon the word increasing in size, the it knocks the last word on that line to the next line (basically forces a word warp). Even though some phrases may word, upon resizing the browser I stumble upon this problem again.

**My question:** This isn't the most technical way of putting it but - is there some kind of word wrap value where I can essentially 'freeze' everything in place, or perhaps while the mouse is over that line, allocate extra space for its width to accomodate the spacing?

**Code summary:**

*HTML* file - only one paragraph value in the body. The innerHTML is replaced from the .js file before loading.

*CSS* - handles the positioning, padding and word-wrap.

*JS* - 'Phrase' is the variable holding the text, then there is some code to split it into an array, give each word its own class, then update the innerHTML of the html file. JQuery used to animate each word with that class when the mouse is hovered over it.

Full disclosure, I am very new to the web development field and would really appreciate any advice/feedback/articles to help me solve this one!

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let phrase = "I am an Interactive Webpage set on Frustrating the Guy trying to CODE me";
  let phraseArray = phrase.split(" ");
  let htmlArray = phraseArray.map(word => {
    return "<span class='word'>" + word + "</span>"
  })
  let finalPhrase = htmlArray.join(" ");
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = finalPhrase;

  $(".word").on("mouseenter", event => {
    $(event.currentTarget).animate({
      fontSize: "80px"
    }, 400);
  }).on("mouseleave", event => {
    $(event.currentTarget).animate({
      fontSize: "60px"
    }, 250);
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #5F5F5F;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: "Major Mono Display", monospace;
  padding: 10%;
  margin: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 160%;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Major+Mono+Display" rel="stylesheet">
<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: Don’t mess with font-sizes on hover, that usually gives terrible results. Apply a `scale` transformation to increase the displayed size of the element a tiny bit instead. Transformations do not change the initial space requirements of an element, so it won’t affect the rest of the text.

Comment: Thank you @Rory - Will look into some options using *scale* now :)